# How to write optimized query for multiple prioritize conditional joins in SQL server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, optimization, set-operations

The scenario I'm after for is :

```
Result = Nothing
CollectionOfTables = Tbl1, Tbl2, Tbl3
While(True){
  CurrentTable = GetHighestPriorityTable(CollectionOfTables)
  If(CurrentTable) = Nothing Then Break Loop;
  RemoveCurrentTableFrom(CollectionOfTables)
  ForEach ID in CurrentTable as TempRow {
    If(Result.DoesntContainsId(ID)) Then Result.AddRow(TempRow)
  }
}
```

Assume I have following three tables.
<kbd>Id</kbd><kbd>Name</kbd>Table1, Priority 1
 
<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>John</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>Mary</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>Elsa</kbd>

<kbd>Id</kbd><kbd>Name</kbd>Table2, Priority 2
<kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>Steve</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>Max</kbd>
<kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>Peter</kbd>

<kbd>Id</kbd><kbd>Name</kbd>Table3, Priority 3
<kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>Frank</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>Harry</kbd>
<kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>Mona</kbd>

Here is the final result I need.

<kbd>Id</kbd><kbd>Name</kbd>Result
<kbd>1</kbd>  <kbd>John</kbd>
<kbd>2</kbd>  <kbd>Mary</kbd>
<kbd>3</kbd>  <kbd>Elsa</kbd>
<kbd>4</kbd>  <kbd>Peter</kbd>
<kbd>5</kbd>  <kbd>Harry</kbd>
<kbd>6</kbd>  <kbd>Mona</kbd>

A few tips to keep in mind.
Number of actual tables is 10.
Number of rows per table exceeds 1 Million.
It's not necessary to use join in query, but because of amount of data I'm working with the query must be optimized and used set-operations in SQL not a Cursor script.

Comment: What (sub-optimal) solution have you come up with so far?

Comment: @ChrisFlynn Actually I don't know SQL so nothing!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a way to do it using `UNION` and `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
;With Cte As
(
    Select  Id, Name, 1 As Prio
    From    Table1
    Union All
    Select  Id, Name, 2 As Prio
    From    Table2
    Union All
    Select  Id, Name, 3 As Prio
    From    Table3
), Ranked As
(
    Select  Id, Name, Row_Number() Over (Partition By Id Order By Prio) As RN
    From    Cte
)
Select  Id, Name
From    Ranked
Where   RN = 1
Order By Id Asc;
```